# Is this program recursive? If not, how do I make it recursive?

Tags: java, string, file-io, recursion, java.util.scanner

For my programming class, I was told to make a program that uses recursion. I was confused and went to see my friend who was already in the class and he showed me this program. I thought recursion had to use things like r1(x-1), etc. Is it actually recursive? If it's not, how do you make it recursive?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class ReverseFile
{
    private static Scanner infile;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        infile= new Scanner(new File("hw_1.txt"));
        r1();
    }
    public static void r1()
    {
        String s;
        if (infile.hasNextLine())
        {
            s = infile.nextLine();
            r1();
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's technically recursive, but not a great example of where you would want to use recursion, since you could use a `while` loop to do the same thing.

Comment: It will run properly as it has a exit state defined as infile.hasnextLine()

Answer (score 6):

It is recursive as `r1` calls itself. The fact that no arguments are passed to `r1` doesn't matter.